# Is there any way to remove pet's ownership?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Previously I make all my animals has their owner except the cats. 
Now when I'm thinking of keeping only goat, sheep,dogs and kill others. 
I realize I can't cancel ownership.

After searching on Google, I found some ways:

1.Kill the pet with magma or trap etc... ,but will make dwarf unhappy

2.Kill the dwarf, but almost EVERY dwarf has pet, means I need to kill every dwarf.

So, is there anyway to turn the pet back to "no owner" condition? 
Like mod, dwarf therapist, DFhack, or change through the raw files ?

Comment: is there no way of setting the owner of the pet by selecting it after it has been given an owner? Sounds like something Toady needs to add to the change list!

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question. There are plenty of preventive measures, but when it comes to your situation your options are limited. Besides killing the pet or owner, editing files seems like the only other way. I have no idea what files you need to change, or even if you can change it, but its just something you gotta look for on your own.

Comment: If you make a really nice cat-murdering chamber ([like this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=56389.msg1248075#msg1248075)) with engravings and a fancy lever then the dwarf will probably be happier than when they went in!

Answer (score 2):

Once a pet is given to a dwarf (or in the case of cats, selected by a cat) then you have no power to change it other than letting the dwarf succumb to some [!!!FUN!!!.](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Pet)

Once the fun has occurred, you may assign the animal to another dwarf, or butcher / pasture as required however they will keep their name.